# Spring boot stateless form login /oauth/authorize

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

Is it possible to create a form login page, where the session creation policy `SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS`.
When I configure it without `sessionCreationPolicy`, the login works.

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http.csrf().disable()
                .and()
                  .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                  .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll();
        // @formatter:on
    }
}
```

When logging in, the `POST` will be send to `/login` and apperantly it will look in the session to redirect it back to the `/oauth/authorize` page (if you were coming from there).

But when I add:

```
http.sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
```

It does not know where to redirect it to after login. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not make this work with the `.formLogin()` options. 
What I did is create a new MVC controller, where you could post your username and password. Authenticate against AuthenticationManager, if login was successful, forward the request to where `/oauth/authorize` is locating.